# How I follow a function with inline asm step by step on Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode6

A have a constructor that uses some inline ASM.

In the middle of that ASM, a destructor of a variable of the object is called, and the constructor that has the ASM gets called again with invalid inputs and the code crashes.

When I am trying to debug, even using step into, everything go fine, until it reaches the inline asm line, then as soon as I press "step into" the program adds the destructor and erroneous constructor call to the stack and crashes.

How I step into the inline ASM (including the setup part, where the input variables are copied into registers) to see what is going on?

Comment: I don't use xcode, but Visual Studio (Windows) has an option for "Go To Disassembly" (right click on the code line while debugging).  This opens up a Disassembly window.  Single stepping in that window walks individual asm instructions.  Might be something to look for in xcode.  You might also post the asm here (assuming it's not huge).  Maybe the problem is obvious.

Comment: I tried that in Xcode before asking the question, the problem is that it still steps using the C/C++/Obj-C code instead.

Also, I found out the problem wasn't in my ASM, I wanted to know why my ASM was bizarre interacting with the rest of the code, I found out that Clang has some nasty bug (when I use a text label in ASM, clang inserts lots of padding, random memory reads and writes, and jumps to some C++ constructors and destructors in a seemly random fashion too, if I get the exact same code, but switch to number labels, then it works...)